# Excel - sumifs dynamic array literal

Tags: arrays, excel, if-statement, literals

```
=SUM(SUMIFS('Output'!$H$50:$H$69,'Output'!$C$50:$C$69,{"*PLoan","Deficit Loan"},'Output'!$G$50:$G$69,X97:AC97))
```

I have the above array formula. `X97:AC97` is where I have my array literal and the values in this array literal are conditioned on some other parameters (let's say the values are a,b,c,d,e if the conditions are met). Because the values are conditional, it might show up as a "" "" "" e "". So in the sumifs array formula it takes the array literal as values {"a","","","","e",""}, which causes an error. How do I make it so that the array is {"a","e"}?

edit: I realized after much effort that sumifs might not be the correct method as it requires alignment. For example, I might have a (1,0) criteria met from {PLoan, Deficit Loan} while `X97:AC97` = (0,1,0,0,0,0). I do want the sum for that number but it won't sum due to the mismatch.

I got the below to work. If anyone can think of a way to incorporate wildcards as part of my string search, let me know...

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(ISNUMBER(MATCH('Output'!$G$50:$G$69,$X$97:$AC$97,0)*MATCH('Output'!$C$50:$C$69,{"PLoan","Operating Deficit Loan"},0))*('Output'!$H$50:$H$69),0))
```

Comment: Hi. In essence what is the aim of the last condition in the sumif? Are you trying to say *"match G with any value in X97:AC97"*? If that's the intent, the formula doesn't do that. Can you provide more details on the objective?

Comment: @A.S.H hey ash, yes that's my intent. I want to sum only the criteria from x97:ac97 in the data G. I thought this 'Output'!$G$50:$G$69,X97:AC97) is in essence 'Output'!$G$50:$G$69,{"a","","","","e",""})

Comment: I see, but `SUMIFS` requires *alignment* in the criteria. So it will include columns where, for instance, `(C matches "*Ploan"  and G matches X97) or (C matches "Deficit loan"  and G matches Y97)`. See what I mean? We may need to write it differently.

Comment: @ash yeah that was the problem I was facing with the mismatch in alignment. I rewrote it and got it to work, I'll write it in the edit.

Comment: @A.S.H please see my edit. I think I got it to work. Would you know of a way to incorporate a wildcard string search into that formula?

Comment: I find it difficult to use a wildcard on the right-hand-side of that `Match`. If it's only to match anything ending with "PLoan", the following seems to work: `=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(MATCH(Output!$G$50:$G$69,$X$97:$AC$97,0))*((RIGHT(Output!$C$50:$C$69, 5) = "PLoan") + (Output!$C$50:$C$69="Operating Deficit Loan"))*Output!$H$50:$H$69)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

---

`COUNTIF(S)`/`SUMIF(S)` do not necessarily "require alignment" of the criteria being passed. It all depends upon what it is you wish to count.

If you require a count which comprises all combinations of the two sets of criteria, then it is sufficient that the two arrays containing those criteria be orthogonal.

At the moment, both of the criteria arrays which you are passing are of the same vector-type, i.e. row-vectors, since:

`X97:AC97`

is clearly a row- (horizontal) vector, as also is:

`{"*PLoan","Deficit Loan"}`

since, for English-language versions of Excel, the comma and semicolon represent, respectively, separators within row (horizontal) and column (vertical) array constants.

As such, in your case you simply need to transpose one of these two arrays, viz:

`=SUM(SUMIFS(Output!$H$50:$H$69,Output!$C$50:$C$69,{"*PLoan";"Deficit Loan"},Output!$G$50:$G$69,X97:AC97))`

(We could also transpose the other, viz:

`=SUM(SUMIFS(Output!$H$50:$H$69,Output!$C$50:$C$69,{"*PLoan","Deficit Loan"},Output!$G$50:$G$69,TRANSPOSE(X97:AC97)))`

or else move the entries within `X97:AC97` to some other, vertical, range.)

See [here](https://excelxor.com/2014/09/28/countifs-multiple-or-criteria-for-one-or-two-criteria_ranges/) for more information.

Regards

Comment: I didn't realize commas and semicolons = horizontal/vertical arrays. Thank you for the insightful answer and article.